# Can Braum's Unbreakable shield tank Caitlyn's Yordle Snap Trap?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Braum's Unbreakable shield tank Caitlyn's Yordle Snap Trap? By 'tank' I mean will Braum not be rooted when coming near the trap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be triggered, but he will not take any damage, so he will just be rooted. The shield only blocks projectiles.